# RNN: Tensor flow Results

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to built an RNN. I try to predict Y with a few X values. If X is only a data series consisting of old Ys the results look ok. But if I use additional data infos (additional different Xs) I get strange results. Y is only 1 or -1 but I get the follwoing predictions even for the train set? Is that possible or must there be an error in the code? The data is normalized before being used.

[image]

I use 9 inputs (one being old Ys) and 1 output.

```
n_inputs = 9 
n_neurons = 100 
n_outputs = 1
n_layers = 4
learning_rate = 0.0001
batch_size = 50
n_epochs = 100 
train_set_size = x_train.shape[0]
test_set_size = x_test.shape[0]
tf.reset_default_graph()
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_inputs])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_outputs])

    # LSTM  
    layers = [tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=n_neurons, activation=tf.nn.elu)
            for layer in range(n_layers)]

    multi_layer_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(layers)
    rnn_outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(multi_layer_cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)
    stacked_rnn_outputs = tf.reshape(rnn_outputs, [-1, n_neurons]) 
    stacked_outputs = tf.layers.dense(stacked_rnn_outputs, n_outputs)
    outputs = tf.reshape(stacked_outputs, [-1, n_steps, n_outputs])
    outputs = outputs[:,n_steps-1,:] # keep only last output of sequence

    # Cost function
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(outputs - y))

    #optimizer to CHANGE IX:
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate) 
    training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

    # Fitting the model
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    input_graph_def = graph.as_graph_def()
    with tf.Session() as sess: 
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for iteration in range(int(n_epochs*train_set_size/batch_size)):
            x_batch, y_batch = get_next_batch(batch_size) # fetch the next training batch 
            sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X: x_batch, y: y_batch}) 
            if iteration % int(5*train_set_size/batch_size) == 0:
                mse_train = loss.eval(feed_dict={X: x_train, y: y_train}) 
                mse_valid = loss.eval(feed_dict={X: x_valid, y: y_valid}) 
                print('%.2f epochs: MSE train/valid = %.6f/%.6f'%(
                    iteration*batch_size/train_set_size, mse_train, mse_valid))
```

Comment: My guess is that your predictions are an expression of the model's confidence in its guess - it seems like your inputs offer a weak signal to your desired output

Comment: you might want share some code if you want us to find the issue. (anything you find relevant)

Comment: thanks guys, I will add some info and code in the question

Comment: any additional input?